# How to use Graph API to read "Multiple lines of text" fields in SharePoint Online?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph, graph-api

I use PowerShell to automate tons of tasks based on content maintained in SharePoint, on-prem.  We are moving several sites to SharePoint Online and I need to update my scripts.  I've chosen to use Graph API because of the other data I can start to access and build automation upon.

The code listed below works great to pull basic information, but I've just discovered that when I pull list items, either as a set or individually, I do not get fields that are of type "Multiple lines of text".

Is the Graph API able to pull these values?  If so, I'd really appreciate a code example in either PowerShell or C#.

Edit: I have tried explicitly specifying the columns (ex: "expand=fields(select=id,Title,Column1)") but that does not work.

```
$ClientID = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
$TenantName = "mytenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$ClientSecret = "secret"
$Resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$ReqTokenBody = @{
    Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
    Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    client_Id     = $ClientID
    Client_Secret = $ClientSecret
} 
$TokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
$ExpireTime = (Get-Date).AddMinutes($TokenResponse.expires_in)

# SharePoint Site Information
# Use Site Name in URI
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($TokenResponse.access_token)"} -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompanysites.sharepoint.com:/sites/SiteName" -method Get

# Each item in $Items has a 'fields' property with most fields.
$Items = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($TokenResponse.access_token)"} `
    -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompanysites.sharepoint.com,720f24c5-8f69-4dd5-ab5c-7833f9f6d40f,623ecce3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-603e514fbf47/lists/2BC83843-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7D2BABC6A5C3/items?expand=fields" -method Get

# Individual List Item
$Item = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($TokenResponse.access_token)"} `
    -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/mycompanysites.sharepoint.com,720f24c5-8f69-4dd5-ab5c-7833f9f6d40f,623ecce3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-603e514fbf47/lists/2BC83843-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-7D2BABC6A5C3/items/100" -method Get
$Item.fields
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve specific columns of list? If yes then you can use `expand=fields(select=id,Title,Column1,Column2)`. This might help you in retrieving "Multiple lines of text" column data.

Comment: Thanks, but that does *not* retrieve columns of type "Multiple lines of text".

Comment: I have announcement list and I tried the same call using Graph API Explorer and it is retrieving "Body" column which is "Multiple lines of text: Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)
" type. `items?expand=fields(select=id,Title,Body)`

Comment: OK... let me dig in and see if I did something wrong...